# TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__(...).slicebox is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying Slicebox Images. But its always showing an Error  slicebox is not a function.

How to resolve this error?

Am importing following files,

```
 import '../../ExternalReferences/css/slicebox.css';
 import '../../ExternalReferences/css/custom.css';
 import '../../ExternalReferences/css/demo.css';
 //import { $ } from 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js';
 import '../../ExternalReferences/js/jquery.min.js';
 // import '../../ExternalReferences/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js';
 //import '../../ExternalReferences/js/modernizr.custom.46884.js';
 import '../../ExternalReferences/js/jquery.slicebox.js';
```

Here is my function,

```
 $(function() {
      var Page =(function() {

        var $navArrows = $( '#nav-arrows' ).hide(),
          $navDots = $( '#nav-dots' ).hide(),
          $nav = $navDots.children( 'span' ),
          $shadow = $( '#shadow' ).hide(),
         // slicebox = ($( '#sb-slider' )as any).slicebox( {
           // $( '#sb-slider' ).slicebox( {
            //slicebox = (jQuery( '#sb-slider' )as any).slicebox( {
              slicebox=($("#sb-slider")as any). slicebox ({
            onReady : function() {

              $navArrows.show();
              $navDots.show();
              $shadow.show();

                       orientation : 'v';
                        perspective : 1200;
                        cuboidsCount : 5;
                        cuboidsRandom : false;
                        maxCuboidsCount : 5;
                        disperseFactor : 0;
                        colorHiddenSides : '#222';
                        sequentialFactor : 150;
                        Speed : 600;
                        easing : 'ease';
                        autoplay : true;
                        interval: 3000;
                        fallbackFadeSpeed : 300; 

            },
            onBeforeChange : function( pos ) {

              $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
              $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

            }
          } ),
          
          init = function() {

            initEvents();
            
          },
          initEvents = function() {

            // add navigation events
            $navArrows.children( ':first' ).on( 'click', function() {

              slicebox.next();
              return false;

            } );

            $navArrows.children( ':last' ).on( 'click', function() {
              
              slicebox.previous();
              return false;

            } );

            $nav.each( function( i ) {
            
              $( this ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
                
                var $dot = $( this );
                
                if( !slicebox.isActive() ) {

                  $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                  $dot.addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                
                }
                
                slicebox.jump( i + 1 );
                return false;
              
              } );
              
            } );

          };

          return { init : init };

      })();
     
      

      Page.init();
      
    });
```

Is console its shows an error **TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__(...).slicebox is not a function**

How to i solve this Slice box is not a function error?
Is it possible?

Thanks,
Dhinesh

Comment: Why do you use `as any`? Can't you not just do `slicebox = $("#sb-slider").slicebox({`. Also check your network tab in the console to check if the jquery.sliderbox.js is loaded correctly

Comment: If i do not put any am getting error "Property 'slicebox' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>' ".. That's why am putting any. - Dhinesh